# how to make URL using Folder/SubFolder/Controller/Action in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

How to specify URL like `DomainName/Admin/Folder/Controller/Action/Parameters` in Asp.net MVC?Is It Require Routing?any one has any idea?please help me.

Comment: Show us an example of what you want to achieve and why... and please "It is urgent" and all the begging is out of place here.

Answer (score 2):

The routing framework is not filesystem based. It has no concept of what folder(s) the controller is in. You can get part of what you want via Areas, which allow you to group controllers under a common directory, but this is more than just a simple it directory. It has an actual class component that the routing framework uses in creating and interpreting the route. So for example, you could add an Area and then get a URL like:

```
/AreaName/ControllerName/ActionName/Parameters
```

But that's as far as you can take it.

Your only other option would be to use custom routes or attribute routing to "fake" the URLs you want. In other words, it still would have nothing to do with the actual filesystem path, but you could could define that the route should be prefixed with the static component of path you wanted.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "Folder/SubFolder/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Or with attribute routing, you'd decorate your controller(s) with the `RoutePrefix` attribute:

```
[RoutePrefix("Folder/SubFolder/Foo")]
public class FooController : Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "area", class="class", etc })
```

Comment: i want url like Domain/Folder/SubFolder/Controller/ActionName/Partameters

Comment: This will provide the domain for you and as much as MVC understands.  See Chris Pratts answer for a great explanation on that

Comment: @MattBodily hello, i need url like http://myportname/controllername/actionname/foldername/filename , how would i get this?

Comment: the port should automatically be pulled as part of the domain.  adding folders to the end will be tricky.  you might be able to do it with @Url.Action() + "foldername/filename".  I have never used that structure so not sure.  good luck

Answer (score 0):

I Have faced same type of issue in my project. Specifying href for menus or for redirection fails when they keep that is folder subfolder.

**Better option would be  href with Url.action in html links.**

```
<a class="nav-link"  href="@Url.Action("ActionmethodName", "Controller Name", new { name = "John", contact = "calgary, vancouver" })">Home</a>
```

**Use Full path Url for Ajax Calls:**
specify full url for url param for ajax calls.